# What is the standard to compute volume profile using OHLCV data?

Tags: equities, technical-analysis, volume

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000502040-volume-profile/

Ideally, the volume profile should be computed using tick data. But such data may not be readily available. Given only OHLCV data, is there any research on what is the best way to compute volume profile (in stock daily chart)?

Comment: Can you describe your input data and desired output in more detail? What is missing in your OHCLV data?

Comment: If you only have daily OHCLV data, but let say the main volume is at a certain price, OHCLV data won't tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

When faced with the same problem I just assumed that the volume is normally distributed across the high/low range of the bar as exemplified by the following Octave code snippet

```
ticks = norminv( linspace( 0 , 1 , vol( ii ) + 2 ) , ( high( ii ) + low( ii ) ) / 2 , ( high( ii ) - low( ii ) ) / 6 ) ;
ticks = floor( ticks( 2 : end - 1 ) ./ tick_size .+ tick_size ) .* tick_size ;
[ vals , bin_centres ] = hist( ticks , unique( ticks ) ) ;
```

I blogged about this approach at https://dekalogblog.blogspot.com/2020/05/market-profile-chart-in-octave.html, from which the following is taken

"*What this does is create vol(ii)+2 linearly spaced tick values from 0 to 1, where vol(ii) is the tick volume for an aggregated period, i.e. an ohlc bar, and transforms these into normally distributed ticks with a mean of the midpoint of the bar and an assumed standard deviation of one sixth the high-low range, rounded to the nearest whole tick. The hist function then provides the counts of ticks per level (vals) at levels (bin_centres).*"

A typical plot of such is

[image: this]

(pay attention to the histogram on the y-axis compared to the following TPO chart on the same data)

[image]

As can be seen, the two charts are broadly similar. These (daily) profiles are built up from the OHLCV of 10 minute candlesticks/bars.

Ideally of course, as you stated in your question, you should drill down to tick level data, but if this is not available a compromise is to use the highest frequency data available to you. The following volume profile chart is built up of 5 second OHLCV data, with the addition of 10 minute "mini profiles" instead of normal candlesticks/bars.

[image]

A more complete description of this chart and the assumptions behind it is at

https://dekalogblog.blogspot.com/2021/08/another-iterative-improvement-of-my.html